# best approach to resolve string values

Tags: java, string

I have one string pattern given below:

```
{a:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS}_{b:name}_{c:F}
```

I have to get values corresponding to `a`, `b` and `c`.

Which is the best approach to do this in java.

Comment: Is your data JSON by any chance?

Comment: No..@domsson...just a string format

Comment: **Also, important**: your question is low-quality as is. You should read up on [ask] and provide your approach, if any, as a [mcve]. Second, you have marked **none** of the answers on any of your other questions as *accepted*. That means it is very unlikely you will receive further help. Please go back to your other questions and fix their issues first.

Comment: You want to look at regex.

Comment: I guess the best approach is to [learn how to use regular expressions, patterns, matchers etc.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), and write a program.

Comment: Ever heard of regex (short for Regular Expression)? If not, take a look into it.

Comment: Seeing how you already received several answers, let me add this: you don't *need* regex for this. Personally, I'm horrible with regex. Since I don't like to use code I don't fully understand, I prefer using [Java's String methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) instead, if possible. In your case, it would be perfectly possible. Just look into `split()` and the like.

Comment: @domsson it is a good idea but i don't get, can you please share the solution so you can help us understand this solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to extract this information for example you can use `\{[a-z]:(.*?)\}` which mean get any thing between `open { followed by any character followed by :` and the close `}`, you can use :

```
String str = "{a:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS}_{b:name}_{c:F}";
String regex = "\\{[a-z]:(.*?)\\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {                                                
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Outputs**

```
yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS
name
F
```

#### regex demo

Comment: Well, here I am, telling OP that he's unlikely to receive help without improving their questions and accepting provided answers... and seeing three answers come in within a couple of minutes. ;)

Comment: @domsson yes this is correct but we see that the OP is stack in which way should follow i suggest this solution maybe it can be the start point for him/her, i'm wrong?

Comment: It's wrong to answer bad questions. Remember that the purpose of the site is to be a **repository of good questions and answers for people to search**. It is **not** a help site. In creating an answer with a positive vote you have prevented this bad question from being automatically deleted.

Comment: @RealSkeptic if it is bad question it should be closed for a long time, i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can go with regular expressions (maybe modify it to be more suitable for you):

```
String testString= "{1:201707311304}{2:name}{3:F}";
String regex = "\{(\w+):\w+\}\{(\w+):\w+\}\{(\w+):\w+\}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testString);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    String a = matcher.group(1);
    String b = matcher.group(2);
    String c = matcher.group(3);
    System.out.println("a = " + a + ", b = " + b + ", c = " + c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String input = "{a:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS}_{b:name}_{c:F}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([a-z]):(.*?)\\}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            String name = m.group(1);
            String value = m.group(2);
            System.err.println( name + "=[" + value + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Outputs:
a=[yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS]
b=[name]
c=[F]